# Convert string to a epoch time in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, epoch

I am trying to convert string in following format: `20130817T140000Z`(17th Aug 2013 at 14:00) to [epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (seconds since 1970) in an MS Excel 2013.

Tried cell formatting, but it doesn't work with `T` and `Z` or the format in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will convert your date into somethign Excel will understand, If you have your date in Cell A1, Then convert that into Epoch Time

```
=(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2)) + TIME(MID(A1,10,2),MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,14,2))-25569)*86400)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string to convert is in cell B1 you can use the following with a custom format on the cell to get the date/time.

```
=DATE(MID(B1,1,4),MID(B1,5,2),MID(B1,7,2))+TIME(MID(B1,10,2),MID(B1,12,2),MID(B1,14,2))
```

The custom format is:

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

Comment: @Fearghal You do realize this does not even answer your question, correct? This gets the Excel Time, or a Number from 1/1/1900, you asked for Epoch, a time from 1/1/1970.

Comment: Yes but i settled for datetime - i can do conversion myself. If you want to post the epoch time solution too, that would be great.

Comment: The base of this issue is the conversion of a string to a datetime value. This resolves that issue. I agree that it doesn't convert to Epoch, but it gives a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
A1=20130817T140000Z
A2=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2))
A3=(DATEDIF("01/01/1970 00:00:00",A2,"D")+TIME(MID(A1,10,2),MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,14,2)))*24*60*60
```

`A1` is your input date as text, `A2` is a formatted date, and `A3` is a seconds difference between your date and epoch start date.

Useful [link](http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/#asp)

**Update:** based on @user2140261 suggestions.

Comment: I do not think this is correct, I think DateDif is messing up your calculations, Refer t5o my answer, I manually get the Difference by subtracting 1/1/1970 (25569), then multiply by the Seconds 86400, While you are also doing it by seconds (24*60*60 = 86400) i think your `DateDif` function is off, this function is known to mess up dates, you can research this, and that is the exact reason it is not supported by excel, no help.

Comment: It actual is not the DateDif function, it is because you are dropping the time value when you use the DateDif, Try instead, `A2=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2))` And `A3=(DATEDIF("01/01/1970 00:00:00",A2,"D")+TIME(MID(A1,10,2),MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,14,2)))*86400`

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the date with accuracy to the minute. You can follow the pattern to get seconds if necessary.

```
=DATE(VALUE(LEFT(A1,4)),VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,6),2)),VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,8),2)))+VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,11),2))/24+VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,13),2))/(24*60)
```

Comment: This is extremly convoluted, and only gets the Excel Time, not the Epoch Time.Plus the OP is asking for Seconds accurancy, not Minute.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this version to convert your string to Epoch time

`=(TEXT(LEFT(A1,8)&MID(A1,10,6),"0000-00-00 00\:00\:00")-25569)*86400`

This uses `TEXT` function to convert your string into a string that looks like a valid date/time - when you subtract 25569 (1/1/1970) that will co-erce that string to a valid  date/time and the result can be multiplied by the number of seconds in a day to get Epoch time