# Convert a string to MM/DD/YYYY date format in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a table from imdb.com and I want to convert one of the fields to a format that Excel understands to be a date (IMDBs is just understood to be an arbitrary string).

An example of the format they use is: "Wed May 27 00:00:00 2015". I would like to convert to this to the "MM/DD/YYYY" format. How would I go about this using Excel?

Comment: Just massaged the post a little bit to make it (hopefully!) a little easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
=TEXT(DATE(RIGHT(A1, 4), MATCH(TRIM(RIGHT(LEFT(A1, 7), 4)), {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Sep","Aug","Oct","Nov","Dec"}, 0), TRIM(RIGHT(LEFT(A1, 10), 2))), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

*Don't forget, to run this formula you must press Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter.*

The above formula assumes that all of your dates will be in the exact same format as you posted. But if not, you can change the values in the `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions and the month array as appropriate.

Here is a run down of how this works:

1) It finds the year from the string

```
RIGHT(A1, 4)
```

2) It finds the month from the string

```
RIGHT(LEFT(A1, 7), 4)
```

3) Finds the index of the month from an array

```
MATCH(TRIM(RIGHT(LEFT(A1, 7), 4)), {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Sep","Aug","Oct","Nov","Dec"}, 0)
```

4) Finds the date from the string

```
TRIM(RIGHT(LEFT(A1, 10), 2))
```

5) Converts it to a `DATE` value using the `DATE` function

```
DATE(RIGHT(A1, 4), MATCH(TRIM(RIGHT(LEFT(A1, 7), 4)), {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Sep","Aug","Oct","Nov","Dec"}, 0), TRIM(RIGHT(LEFT(A1, 10), 2)))
```

6) Formats the result using the `TEXT` function

The `TEXT` function allows you to format a cell value any way that you like.

See [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20D5AC4D-7B94-49FD-BB38-93D29371225C?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) for more information about this function.

Here is a screen shot of this formula working:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the answer.

The first step is to convert your string to an Excel datetime.  That is covered in this answer:  [Convert string to a epoch time in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557018/convert-string-to-a-date-in-excel) .

The second step is to set the display format to `MM/DD/YY` which is done using normal cell formatting.  See: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e for an example.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the values in place, select the cells you wish to convert and run this short macro:

```
Sub Datemaker()
    Dim r As Range, d As Date
    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Text, " ")
        d = DateValue(ary(1) & " " & ary(2) & " " & ary(4))
        r.Value = d
        r.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the well defined format, another formula to convert the value to an Excel Date:

```
=--REPLACE(MID(A1,5,20),7,9,",")
```

You can then format it as you wish